# Pyqt: custom frame doesn't detect mouse click under mouseMoveEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a custom Frame for a Qgraphicswidget. I have come across two problems, First, one being that clicks are not being detected under MouseMoveEvent, that is `event.button()` always returns 0 even if there is a mouse click. Second, is that my `setCursor()` doesn't change the cursor. Here is my code under the custom frame class.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QEvent, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QPainter, QBrush, qRgb, QPolygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Frame(QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, option=[], margin=0):
        super(Frame, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.options = option
        self._margin = margin
        self.start_pos = None
        # self.parent.setViewport(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: lightblue')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.show()

    def update_option(self, option):
        self.options = option

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        qp = QPainter(self)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.gray)
        qp.drawPolygon(self._triangle)

    def _recalculate_triangle(self):
        p = QPoint(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)

        self._triangle = QPolygon([p, q, r])
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._recalculate_triangle()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
                event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
            ):
                self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
                self.start_pos = event.pos()
                # print(self.start_pos)

            else:
                self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
                self.start_pos = None

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
            self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        else:
            self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
            self.start_pos = None

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.start_pos is not None:
                self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

                delta = event.pos() - self.start_pos

                self.n_resize(self.width()+delta.x(), self.height()+delta.y())
                self.start_pos = event.pos()

            elif not self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
                self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
                self.start_pos = None

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
        self.start_pos = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def n_resize(self, width, height):
        self.resize(width, height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Frame()
    sys.exit(q.exec())
```

I have also tried using `eventfilter` but of no use.

EDIT:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QPainter, QBrush, QPolygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys



class graphLayout(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.lines = []
        self.draw_grid()
        self.set_opacity(0.3)

        widget = QGraphicsProxyWidget()

        t = stack(self)
        t.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        t.resize(340, 330)

        self.scene.addItem(t)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.show()

    def create_texture(self):
        image = QtGui.QImage(QtCore.QSize(30, 30), QtGui.QImage.Format_RGBA64)

        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(QColor(189, 190, 191))
        pen.setWidth(2)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(image.rect())
        painter.end()

        return image

    def draw_grid(self):

        texture = self.create_texture()
        brush = QBrush()
        # brush.setColor(QColor('#999'))
        brush.setTextureImage(texture)  # Grid pattern.
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(brush)

        borderColor = Qt.black
        fillColor = QColor('#DDD')

    def set_visible(self, visible=True):
        for line in self.lines:
            line.setVisible(visible)

    def delete_grid(self):
        for line in self.lines:
            self.scene.removeItem(line)
        del self.lines[:]

    def set_opacity(self, opacity):
        for line in self.lines:
            line.setOpacity(opacity)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):

        if event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:

            delta = event.angleDelta().y()
            if delta > 0:
                self.on_zoom_in()

            elif delta < 0:
                self.on_zoom_out()

        super(graphLayout, self).wheelEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            self.mousepos = event.localPos()

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):


        # This helps to pan the area
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MidButton:
            delta = event.localPos() - self.mousepos
            h = self.horizontalScrollBar().value()
            v = self.verticalScrollBar().value()

            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(int(h - delta.x()))
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(int(v - delta.y()))

        self.mousepos = event.localPos()

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        self.unsetCursor()
        self.mousepos = event.localPos()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def on_zoom_in(self):

        if self.transform().m11() < 3.375:
            self.setTransformationAnchor(self.AnchorUnderMouse)
            self.scale(1.5, 1.5)

    def on_zoom_out(self):

        if self.transform().m11() > 0.7:
            self.setTransformationAnchor(self.AnchorUnderMouse)
            self.scale(1.0 / 1.5, 1.0 / 1.5)


class stack(QGraphicsWidget):
    _margin = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.options = []
        self.gridlayout = parent

        graphic_layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Vertical, self)

        self.width, self.height = 10, 10

        self.outer_container = Frame(parent, self.options, self._margin)

        self.outer_container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setParent(self.outer_container)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.headerLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.headerLayout.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 0, 0)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.top_bar.setLayout(self.headerLayout)
        self.top_bar.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(30)

        # self.contentLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.contentLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.contentLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.contentLayout.setSpacing(5)

        layout.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        layout.addLayout(self.contentLayout)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.outer_container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setMaximumSize(400, 800)

        self.outer_container.setLayout(layout)

        widget = QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        widget.setWidget(self.outer_container)

        # todo: figure out a way to add top_bar widget
        graphic_layout.addItem(widget)
        graphic_layout.setSpacing(0)
        graphic_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # widget move and resize note: don't touch any of these
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.start_pos = None


    def addHeaderWidget(self, widget=None, column=0, bg_color='green'):
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet(f'background-color:{bg_color};')
        self.headerLayout.addWidget(widget, 0, column)



class Frame(QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, option=[], margin=0):
        super(Frame, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.options = option
        self._margin = margin
        self.start_pos = None
        # self.parent.setViewport(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: lightblue')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.show()

    def update_option(self, option):
        self.options = option

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        qp = QPainter(self)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.gray)
        qp.drawPolygon(self._triangle)

    def _recalculate_triangle(self):
        p = QPoint(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)

        self._triangle = QPolygon([p, q, r])
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._recalculate_triangle()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
                event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
            ):
                self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
                self.start_pos = event.pos()
                # print(self.start_pos)

            else:
                self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
                self.start_pos = None

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
            self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        else:
            self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
            self.start_pos = None

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.start_pos is not None:
                self.parent.viewport().setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

                delta = event.pos() - self.start_pos

                self.n_resize(self.width()+delta.x(), self.height()+delta.y())
                self.start_pos = event.pos()

            elif not self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
                self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
                self.start_pos = None

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.parent.viewport().unsetCursor()
        self.start_pos = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def n_resize(self, width, height):
        self.resize(width, height)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = graphLayout()
    sys.exit(q.exec())
```

Comment: The `mouseEvent.button()` returns the button that *caused* the event, what you need is to call [`buttons()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#button) (note the `s`), which is the button *state* when the event was generated: when you move the mouse the event is *not* generated by any button, so you need to know the actual buttons pressed when the event is generated instead. Besides that, your example is not reproducible, as you didn't explain what is `parent` and your code clearly crashes as `None` has no `viewport` attribute. Please edit your code with a *reproducible* example.

Comment: @musicamante Can u check the edit? I want the cursor to change when it's over the triangle on the bottom right corner of the frame. Also, the click still doesn't work

Comment: Frankly, I have to admit that I find it really hard to help you, as your code is unnecessarily complex and has some serious conceptual issues. For instance, you're creating a `Frame` class with the view as parent, but then you set a QGraphicsProxyWidget for it and add it to a layout inside a GraphicsWidget which doesn't make a lot of sense. Then you make that graphics widget *movable* (which will cause it to be moved when dragging the mouse since you're not filtering mouse events). Also, you're using a subclass of QFrame while not using any of its features, and a plain QWidget would suffice.

Comment: I mean, I *could* try to give an answer, but I will not be able to use any part of your code, as correcting it would anyway require to completely rewrite it from scratch anyway.

Comment: @musicamante I tried to use a custom widget that inherits a QWidget and then used QGraphicsproxyWidget to place it in the view. But using a QgraphicsproxyWidget adds a weird border to it, so I had to make a widget by inheriting QGraphicsWidget.  I am trying to use the frame as a container to place widgets such as buttons and labels inside and the frame has to inherit view so that I can change the cursor when it is over the triangle. I'll be more than happy if you could show me a better way of doing it.

Comment: What "weird border"?

Comment: @musicamante here is a link to that https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/k3ujte/qgraphicsproxywidget_sets_a_border_automatically/

Comment: That's *not* a "weird" border, is the standard rectangle that contains *any* [top level] widget, you would see it even if you show the widget outside the graphics view, if you want rounded borders you must use masking or paint clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various issues on your code, but the base problems are:

- mouse button state cannot be retrieved by `event.button()` in a MouseMove event, and `event.buttons()` should be used instead: the difference is clear: `button()` shows the buttons that *generate* the event (and a mouse move event is obviously *not* generated by any button), `buttons()` shows the button *state* when the event is generated;
- events that are not explicitly managed by an object are *always* propagated to its parent(s), which means that your mouse movements are also possibly processed by the parent widget, then the graphics proxy, the scene, the viewport, the view, etc, and that up to the top level window, until one of the previous objects actually returns `True` from `event()` or an event filter; in your case it results in moving the graphics item, since you enabled the `ItemIsMovable` flag.

I don't know why the cursor is not actually set, but frankly your code is so convoluted that I really cannot find the reason.

Since what you're actually looking for is a way to resize the widget, I suggest you another solution.
While implementing a resizing with custom painting is certainly feasible, in most cases it's well enough to use a [QSizeGrip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html) (as already suggested to you in another post), which is a widget that allows resizing top-level windows and is automatically able to understand which "corner" use for the resizing based on its position. Remember that the *parent* of the QSizeGrip is very important, because it uses it to understand which is its top level window, and, in this case, the "container frame", even if it's in a QGraphicsScene.

Note that QSizeGrip should *not* be added to a layout, and it should always be manually moved according to its *corner* position and the size of its parent (unless it's placed on the top left corner), and since you already need custom painting, it's better to subclass it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class SizeGrip(QtWidgets.QSizeGrip):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        parent.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setFixedSize(30, 30)
        self.polygon = QtGui.QPolygon([
            QtCore.QPoint(10, 20), 
            QtCore.QPoint(20, 10), 
            QtCore.QPoint(20, 20), 
        ])

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize:
            geo = self.rect()
            geo.moveBottomRight(source.rect().bottomRight())
            self.setGeometry(geo)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray)
        qp.drawPolygon(self.polygon)


class Container(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sizeGrip = SizeGrip(self)
        self.startPos = None
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 30)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Container {
                background: lightblue;
                border: 0px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        ''')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.startPos:
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.startPos))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = None


class GraphicsRoundedFrame(QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.container = Container()
        self.setWidget(self.container)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        self.container.layout().addWidget(widget)

    def paint(self, qp, opt, widget):
        qp.save()
        p = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        p.addRoundedRect(self.boundingRect().adjusted(0, 0, -.5, -.5), 4, 4)
        qp.setClipPath(p)
        super().paint(qp, opt, widget)
        qp.restore()


class View(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1024, 768)

        texture = QtGui.QImage(30, 30, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(texture)
        qp.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(189, 190, 191), 2))
        qp.drawRect(texture.rect())
        qp.end()
        scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(texture))

        testFrame = GraphicsRoundedFrame()
        scene.addItem(testFrame)

        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('I am a label'))
        testFrame.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('I am a button'))

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = View()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```